# How do I configure function timeout when hosting NextJS app on AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I have my nextjs app deployed with AWS amplify. I need to extend the timeout setting for the serverless functions, because the operation takes longer than the current max.

Is there a way to do this?

I can only find responses pointing to Lambda, but I don't have my functions set up with lambda. My nextjs /api functions are handled directly by AWS Amplify.

Is there a way to access the configuration? Or do I have to move my functions to Lambda in order to configure this?

PS: Long-time reader, first-time poster - be gentle if I missed any critical info

I can't find setting for this in AWS Amplify:
[AWS Amplify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcbSU.png)

In Lambda its straight forward - should I move my functions to Lambda?
[Lambda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwaGs.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using /api, I believe the build tooling bundles all those files together into one Lambda@Edge function. I don't know if you can set the Lambda's timeout or grant it resource access permissions.

I believe the timeout was increased from 8 seconds to 30 seconds. That's the most you'll get. You can make a lambda run longer, but API Gateway will timeout at 30 seconds. The API will fail, but the lambda will continue running but it's response will be ignored.

Since you're using Amplify, you can very easily `amplify add function` and create your own lambda. You can then set its timeout, set the runtime to the node version you want, give it permissions to access your resources, etc. And you can `amplify add api` to add a rest-api or access it via GraphQL. But beware, those approaches will still timeout at 30 seconds even if you set the Lambda to run for longer than that.

You take the request, stick it in an SQS queue and return the message-id instantly. Insert Seinfeld "yada yada yada", and then the caller can then use the message-id to poll for job complete and get the result.

Or you can make a lambda and use the new Lambda URL to directly invoke the lambda bypassing API Gateway. I wrote-up a [GIST that explains how to](https://gist.github.com/dmost714/82f4d40b921fb1978a4b186f881dc460) do that in Amplify.

Comment: Very insightful - and saved me from trying (and failing) a Lambda function. Thanks @dave! Will hopefully get to use your approach soon

Comment: @trafficleitz how were able to finally solve this ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: I decided to build & host a simple express backend to avoid the timeout problem alltogether